# css Changing the size of a class doesn't work

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am very new to HTML and CSS. That being said, I develop a shiny App (R) and for styling the app, I need to use CSS. (The "shiny"-community did not react to my question), so I try it here:

The app creates plots that are rendered upon user input. Basically, when the user adds a plot, a new line of HTML is added. These plots have different sizes and I want them to align vertically on the webpage.  I added an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzOal.png) for clarification of the "visual" problem.

While I can set a different size of the plot in R, the "container" on the webpage is fix at 400px. I added a picture of the inspection of the webpage [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7ddb.png).

I thought that I can change the height of the rendered plots by using a CSS file aimed at the .class. In the CSS I used the following code:

```
/*css file*/

.shiny-plot-output { height:200px; }
```

However, it doesn't work and even after hours of trying, I haven't found a solution to this. I would be very grateful for any inputs on this.

In case you use R and you would like to use a reproducible example, I created a minimal reproducible example on [github](https://github.com/robur86/alignment_plots).

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just replace **=** by **:** in your css file.

```
.shiny-plot-output { height:200px; }
```

Comment: Thanks. However, it doesn't change the size of the "container". Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Use important to overwrite that inline style by like this in your css                  
      .shiny-plot-output { height:200px!important; }

Comment: Wow! You really saved me here :) This totally did the trick! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Use code the following:

```
.shiny-plot-output { height:200px; }
```

Your code has an `=` sign which needs to be an `:`.

`CSS` general syntax is the following way:

```
selector {style : value}
```

- **selector**: Is the element to be styled
- **style**: The property which needs to be for example `margin`, `font-size` etc.
- **Value:** The value which we want to give the `CSS` property.

Comment: Thanks Willem. I have played around with the css file before posting here and by rewriting it, I accidentally added a = rather than :. However, also by changin the syntax, it doesn't work. As selector, I used the .class (.shiny-plot-output), but nothing happens. Do you have any other advice?